# DNS not resolving while deploying docker container in CentOS

Tags: docker, centos, centos7, centos8

While trying to deploy a a docker container in Cent-OS getting the following 
error ( DNS not resolving inside the container)

```
error Command failed.
Exit code: 128
Command: git
Arguments: ls-remote --tags --heads https://github.com/Asymmetrik/node-fhir-server-core.git
Directory: /srv/cpr-fhir
Output:
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Asymmetrik/node-fhir-server-core.git/': Could not resolve host: github.com
```

```
**Operating System: CentOS Linux 8 (Core)
Docker version: Version:           19.03.7**
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is happen because docker container not using the native DNS.

Fix

Go to the docker configuration file  ***/lib/systemd/system/docker.service***

append the dns variable in the ExecStart  command as follows

**ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock  --dns 8.8.8.8**